# Titlesec ruins Table of Contents formatting

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec

I'm trying to use the `titlesec` package, but somehow section names in the `\tableofcontents` become overlapped with the TOC numbers and subsection names become improperly indented. Here's an example, where I use the standard classes seen [here](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/layout/titlesec.pdf) (3.2, p.27) as an example.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Section Title}
\subsection{Subsection Title}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Sorry, but `titlesec` is not compatible with the AMS classes. Just use the `article` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **egreg** mentions in his comment (and as you've already experienced), `titlesec` and `amsart` are not compatible; you have two options:

1. Switch to the standard `article` class.
2. Change `\section`, `\subsection` and `\@secnumfont` as implemented in `amsart.cls` to get the desired layout.

Here's an example of the redefinitions for the second option:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Section Title}
\subsection{Subsection Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Probably you will also want to redefine `\specialsection`, whose definition is

```
\def\specialsection{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\centering}}
```

Comment: I added an extra question, but nevermind. I might as well work with the `article` class and alter its default fonts/headings to emulate  `amsart`'s, which is probably easier than dealing with very nitpicky things regarding headers, TOCs, and section headings in `amsart`. Thanks a bunch!