# Mimicking amsart's font sizes in the article class

Tags: fontsize, amsart, article

I've been trying to customize the `tableofcontents` and `sections` to my own liking in the `amsart` class, but a lot (if not all) of the packages for either of these two functions are incompatible with `amsart`. At the suggestion of a [few here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71014/titlesec-ruins-table-of-contents-formatting), I've decided to switch to the `article` class, which easily let me change them to my heart's content. However, I'm a huge fan of `amsart`'s font sizes and headings, and I'd like to emulate that style in the `article` class. I've managed to mimic the headings using `fancyhdr` but I'm at a loss for emulating the font sizes.

[Wikibooks here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Sizing_text) shows the specific differences in the font sizes between `article` and `amsart`.
[image: For the lazy]

I was wondering how I could alter each of `article`'s font sizes (e.g. `\tiny` to `\Huge`) to match the absolute point sizes of `amsart`'s. Perhaps some type of `\renewcommand{\tiny}{\fontsize{7.33325}}` macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have put the stuff for the font sizes of the class `amsart` in a separate package `amssizes`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{amssizes}[2012/09/11 v1.0 Font size stuff from class amsart]

\newcommand{\larger}[1][1]{%
  \count@\@currsizeindex \advance\count@#1\relax
  \ifnum\count@<\z@ \count@\z@ \else\ifnum\count@>12 \count@12 \fi\fi
  \ifcase\count@
    \Tiny\or\Tiny\or\tiny\or\SMALL\or\Small\or\small
    \or\normalsize
    \or\large\or\Large\or\LARGE\or\huge\or\Huge\else\Huge
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\smaller}[1][2]{\larger[-#1]}
\def\@adjustvertspacing{%
  \bigskipamount.7\baselineskip plus.7\baselineskip
  \medskipamount\bigskipamount \divide\medskipamount\tw@
  \smallskipamount\medskipamount \divide\smallskipamount\tw@
  \abovedisplayskip\medskipamount
  \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
  \abovedisplayshortskip\abovedisplayskip
  \advance\abovedisplayshortskip-1\abovedisplayskip
  \belowdisplayshortskip\abovedisplayshortskip
  \advance\belowdisplayshortskip 1\smallskipamount
  \jot\baselineskip \divide\jot 4 \relax
}
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@xsetfontsize\normalsize 6%
  \@adjustvertspacing \let\@listi\@listI}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Tiny}{\@xsetfontsize\Tiny 1}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tiny}{\@xsetfontsize\tiny 2}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\SMALL}{\@xsetfontsize\SMALL 3}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Small}{\@xsetfontsize\Small 4%
  \@adjustvertspacing
  \def\@listi{\topsep\smallskipamount \parsep\z@skip \itemsep\z@skip
    \leftmargin=\leftmargini
    \labelwidth=\leftmargini \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
  }%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\small}{\@xsetfontsize\small 5\@adjustvertspacing}
\def\footnotesize{\Small}
\def\scriptsize{\SMALL}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\large}{\@xsetfontsize\large 7\@adjustvertspacing}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Large}{\@xsetfontsize\Large 8\@adjustvertspacing}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LARGE}{\@xsetfontsize\LARGE 9}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\huge}{\@xsetfontsize\huge{10}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Huge}{\@xsetfontsize\Huge{11}}
\def\@xsetfontsize#1#2{%
  \chardef\@currsizeindex#2\relax
  \edef\@tempa{\noexpand\@setfontsize\noexpand#1%
    \expandafter\ifcase\expandafter\@currsizeindex\@typesizes
      \else{99}{99}\fi}%
  \@tempa
}
\chardef\@currsizeindex=6

\DeclareOption{10pt}{%
  \def\@mainsize{10}  
  \def\@ptsize{0}%    
  \def\@typesizes{%   
    \or{5}{6}\or{6}{7}\or{7}{8}\or{8}{10}\or{9}{11}%
    \or{10}{12}% normalsize
    \or{\@xipt}{13}\or{\@xiipt}{14}\or{\@xivpt}{17}%
    \or{\@xviipt}{20}\or{\@xxpt}{24}%
  }%
}   
\DeclareOption{11pt}{%
  \def\@mainsize{11}% 
  \def\@pt@size{1}%   
  \def\@typesizes{%   
    \or{6}{7}\or{7}{8}\or{8}{10}\or{9}{11}\or{10}{12}%
    \or{\@xipt}{13}% normalsize
    \or{\@xiipt}{14}\or{\@xivpt}{17}\or{\@xviipt}{20}%
    \or{\@xxpt}{24}\or{\@xxvpt}{30}%
  }%
}   
\DeclareOption{12pt}{%
  \def\@mainsize{12}% 
  \def\@ptsize{2}%    
  \def\@typesizes{%   
    \or{7}{8}\or{8}{10}\or{9}{11}\or{10}{12}\or{\@xipt}{13}%
    \or{\@xiipt}{14}% normalsize
    \or{\@xivpt}{17}\or{\@xviipt}{20}\or{\@xxpt}{24}%
    \or{\@xxvpt}{30}\or{\@xxvpt}{30}%
  }%
}   
\DeclareOption{8pt}{%
  \def\@mainsize{8}% 
  \def\@ptsize{8}%   
  \def\@typesizes{%  
    \or{5}{6}\or{5}{6}\or{5}{6}\or{6}{7}\or{7}{8}%
    \or{8}{10}% normalsize
    \or{9}{11}\or{10}{12}\or{\@xipt}{13}%
    \or{\@xiipt}{14}\or{\@xivpt}{17}%
  }%
}   
\DeclareOption{9pt}{%
  \def\@mainsize{9}% 
  \def\@ptsize{9}%   
  \def\@typesizes{%  
    \or{5}{6}\or{5}{6}\or{6}{7}\or{7}{8}\or{8}{10}%
    \or{9}{11}% normalsize
    \or{10}{12}\or{\@xipt}{13}\or{\@xiipt}{14}%
    \or{\@xivpt}{17}\or{\@xviipt}{20}%
  }%
}   
\ExecuteOptions{10pt}
\ProcessOptions*
\normalsize
\endinput
```

The package sets the sizes for the standard size commands. Additionally:

- Macros `\larger` and `\smaller` are available.
- Size command `\Tiny` is added to the standard commands.
- The different font sizes are:

  - `\Tiny`
  - `\tiny`
  - `\SMALL` (`\scriptsize`)
  - `\small` (`\footnotesize`)
  - `\normalsize`
  - `\large`
  - `\Large`
  - `\LARGE`
  - `\huge`
  - `\Huge`

`\sriptsize` and `\footnotesize` are defined as `\SMALL` and `\small`. That allows an easy redefinition of the size.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}

\usepackage[11pt]{amssizes}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \texttt{\textbackslash #1} &
  \ttfamily
  \begingroup
    \csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \f@size pt\\
}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\texttt{\textbackslash @mainsize} & \texttt{\@mainsize}pt \\
\hline
\test{Tiny}
\test{tiny}
\test{scriptsize}
\test{footnotesize}
\test{small}
\test{normalsize}
\test{large}
\test{Large}
\test{LARGE}
\test{huge}
\test{Huge}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Font sizes for 11pt]

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there a difference between using `amssizes` as a package and use it as a `.tex` file for `\input`? (enclosing the document with `\makeatletter`, etc. of course) I'd like the option of sharing my document with others without the hassle of forcing them to install a new package; a lone `.tex` file which is already `\input`'d into the preamble would be simpler.

Comment: `\usepackage` supports global and local options. The size options are important here. The `11pt` can also be given as global option here. Also there is no difference in installing a `.tex` or `.sty` file. They can both put in the current directory or installed in a TDS/texmf tree (below `TDS:tex/latex/`).