# Installing manual package with MiKTeX

Tags: packages, installing, miktex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)

I'm trying to install a custom-made package from [Heiko Oberdiek's answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71124/mimicking-amsarts-font-sizes-in-the-article-class), which I saved as `amssizes.sty`. I put it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc` as necessary, and went to MiKTeX's "Settings (Admin)" application and proceeded to `Refresh FNDB` and `Update Formats`. However, I then go into the "Package Manager (Admin)" application, and I still can't find `amssizes`.

As far as I know, I've proceeded with all the correct steps, and I've tried all sorts of different combinations (without `Update Formats`, with/without (Admin), etc.). If it helps, I also have `Install missing files on-the-fly` denoted with `Yes` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9` is indeed in the root directory. I appreciate any help!

Comment: You shouldn't put your own packages in that directory- instead use `C:\Users\yourusername\Documents\tex\latex`

Comment: Ah, so manually installing packages requires using a custom root directory rather than the default? I'll try that in an hour or two and see what happens; unfortunately, I'm busy at the moment.

Comment: related/relevant: [how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)

Comment: Yea, that was the main guide, along with MiKTeX's documentation, that I followed. It seemed to omit the "make your own root directory" detail.

Comment: Okay, so I added the root directory you recommended (`C:\...\Documents`), put the `*.sty` file into subdirectory `\tex\latex\misc`, refreshed MiKTeX, and it _still_ doesn't appear. Not sure what I haven't done so far.

Comment: I'm in the main chat room, feel free to join; back and forth discussions via comments is discouraged by moderators

Comment: @cmhughes: Sorry I didn't get into the chat room in time; I was in the middle of a lecture so I didn't see your message until now. I apologize for the back-and-forth conversation; hopefully they'll make an exception! @ Kurt: It's installed as administrator, and I've been using all the (Admin) applications. I also changed their properties to always allow administrator access specifically. If I can't solve it sometime by today, I'll try re-installing MiKTeX and see what I can do from there.

Comment: See also [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex) (and [Purpose of local texmf trees](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69487/purpose-of-local-texmf-trees)).

Comment: Why do people always believe that one should at best always do everything as administrator? You want a *user* to find the file. So at first try to get it to work for this user: Create in this user account a local texmf tree in a place where this user has writing rights, move your file to `path/to/root/tex/latex/misc`, register the root *in user mode* (e.g. `initexmf --register-root path\to\root`) and check with `kpsewhich amssizes.sty` if it is found. You can later try to find out, how to install a file in admin mode for all users.

Comment: Duplicate of: [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/78565)